# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

Tags: swift, swift3, nsdate, alamofire, nsdateformatter

I am formatting time that is being passed in. I am getting this error, and I'm trying to figure out what's happening here with it. I'm using the most up to date version of Xcode (v. 8) and am programming in Swift 3. What this error means and how to fix it?

I'm piecing in parts of the code that are relevant to the question so it's not a overload of information here.

```
var date: String {
    if _date == nil {
        _date = ""
    }
    return _date
}

init(weatherDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
    if let temp = weatherDict["temp"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    {
        if let min = temp["min"] as? Double{
            self._lowTemp = ktof(kelvins: min)
        }

        if let max = temp["max"] as? Double{
            self._highTemp = ktof(kelvins: max)
        }
    }

    let unixConvertedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)

    if let date = weatherDict["dt"] as? Double {
        let unixConvertedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
        //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        self._date = unixConvertedDate.dayoftheWeek()
    }
}
```

and then outside of the class, which all the above code is inside of, I have this.

```
extension Date {
func dayoftheWeek() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the extra line `let unixConvertedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)`. You don't need the one between the two `if let` blocks.

Comment: he can also remove the date formatter completely from the init

Comment: BTW why not simply `var date = ""`

Answer (score 0):

```
            if let date = weatherDict["dt"] as? Double {

            let unixConvertedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
            self._date = "\(unixConvertedDate)"
        }

    }

}

extension Date {
    func dayOfTheWeek() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your code. See the help center for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer